# Zend_JSON:Encode messing up - why?

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, utf-8

My Zend_Json is messing up in encoding an object here. I'm encoding an associative array which has two elements:
Element one is another associative array while element 2 is an HTML string. He's goofing up such that the Html string part contains just NULL!!?!?!?!?

Heres the element UNencoded when I do a var_dump on it...sorry for the looong element...
Its very erratic - I don't understand whats wrong here...

```
array (
  'map' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => '1403',
      'name' => 'Amborovy Airport (Philibert Tsiranana Airport)',
      'label' => 'Amborovy Airport (Philibert Tsiranana Airport)',
      'html' => 'Amborovy Airport (Philibert Tsiranana Airport)',
      'lat' => '-0.666944',
      'lng' => '46.3517',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'id' => '6160',
      'name' => 'Generalissimo Francisco de Miranda Airbase',
      'label' => 'Generalissimo Francisco de Miranda Airbase',
      'html' => 'Generalissimo Francisco de Miranda Airbase',
      'lat' => '0.485',
      'lng' => '-66.8436',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'id' => '7808',
      'name' => 'Tirana International Airport',
      'label' => 'Tirana International Airport',
      'html' => 'Tirana International Airport',
      'lat' => '41.4150929722',
      'lng' => '19.7233001667',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'id' => '20881',
      'name' => 'Tiranë Heliport',
      'label' => 'Tiranë Heliport',
      'html' => 'Tiranë Heliport',
      'lat' => 41.315865416667,
      'lng' => 19.888245972222,
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5218',
      'name' => 'Abadan Airport',
      'label' => 'Abadan Airport',
      'html' => 'Abadan Airport',
      'lat' => '0.371111',
      'lng' => '48.2283',
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5330',
      'name' => 'Lar Airport',
      'label' => 'Lar Airport',
      'html' => 'Lar Airport',
      'lat' => '0.673056',
      'lng' => '54.3814',
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      'id' => '7808',
      'name' => 'Tirana International Airport',
      'label' => 'Tirana International Airport',
      'html' => 'Tirana International Airport',
      'lat' => '41.4150929722',
      'lng' => '19.7233001667',
    ),
    7 => 
    array (
      'id' => '20881',
      'name' => 'Tiranë Heliport',
      'label' => 'Tiranë Heliport',
      'html' => 'Tiranë Heliport',
      'lat' => 41.315865416667,
      'lng' => 19.888245972222,
    ),
    8 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5218',
      'name' => 'Abadan Airport',
      'label' => 'Abadan Airport',
      'html' => 'Abadan Airport',
      'lat' => '0.371111',
      'lng' => '48.2283',
    ),
    9 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5225',
      'name' => 'Ahvaz Airport',
      'label' => 'Ahvaz Airport',
      'html' => 'Ahvaz Airport',
      'lat' => '0.337431',
      'lng' => '48.762',
    ),
    10 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5242',
      'name' => 'Ardabil Airport',
      'label' => 'Ardabil Airport',
      'html' => 'Ardabil Airport',
      'lat' => '0.325556',
      'lng' => '48.4242',
    ),
    11 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5243',
      'name' => 'Asalouyeh Airport',
      'label' => 'Asalouyeh Airport',
      'html' => 'Asalouyeh Airport',
      'lat' => '0.481389',
      'lng' => '52.6153',
    ),
    12 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5251',
      'name' => 'Bandar Abbas International Airport',
      'label' => 'Bandar Abbas International Airport',
      'html' => 'Bandar Abbas International Airport',
      'lat' => '0.218056',
      'lng' => '56.3778',
    ),
    13 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5259',
      'name' => 'Birjand Airport',
      'label' => 'Birjand Airport',
      'html' => 'Birjand Airport',
      'lat' => '0.898056',
      'lng' => '59.2661',
    ),
    14 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5278',
      'name' => 'Dezful Airport',
      'label' => 'Dezful Airport',
      'html' => 'Dezful Airport',
      'lat' => '0.434444',
      'lng' => '48.3976',
    ),
    15 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5306',
      'name' => 'Jiroft Airport',
      'label' => 'Jiroft Airport',
      'html' => 'Jiroft Airport',
      'lat' => '0.726944',
      'lng' => '57.6703',
    ),
    16 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5326',
      'name' => 'Konarak Airport',
      'label' => 'Konarak Airport',
      'html' => 'Konarak Airport',
      'lat' => '0.443333',
      'lng' => '60.3819',
    ),
    17 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5330',
      'name' => 'Lar Airport',
      'label' => 'Lar Airport',
      'html' => 'Lar Airport',
      'lat' => '0.673056',
      'lng' => '54.3814',
    ),
    18 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5331',
      'name' => 'Lavan Airport',
      'label' => 'Lavan Airport',
      'html' => 'Lavan Airport',
      'lat' => '0.810278',
      'lng' => '53.3561',
    ),
    19 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5359',
      'name' => 'Parsabad-Moghan Airport',
      'label' => 'Parsabad-Moghan Airport',
      'html' => 'Parsabad-Moghan Airport',
      'lat' => '0.603606',
      'lng' => '47.8815',
    ),
    20 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5361',
      'name' => 'Persian Gulf Airport (Khalije Fars Airport)',
      'label' => 'Persian Gulf Airport (Khalije Fars Airport)',
      'html' => 'Persian Gulf Airport (Khalije Fars Airport)',
      'lat' => '0.379444',
      'lng' => '52.7375',
    ),
    21 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5393',
      'name' => 'Shahid Sadooghi Airport',
      'label' => 'Shahid Sadooghi Airport',
      'html' => 'Shahid Sadooghi Airport',
      'lat' => '0.905',
      'lng' => '54.2764',
    ),
    22 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5411',
      'name' => 'Tabriz International Airport',
      'label' => 'Tabriz International Airport',
      'html' => 'Tabriz International Airport',
      'lat' => '0.133889',
      'lng' => '46.235',
    ),
    23 => 
    array (
      'id' => '1416',
      'name' => 'Arrachart Airport',
      'label' => 'Arrachart Airport',
      'html' => 'Arrachart Airport',
      'lat' => '-0.349167',
      'lng' => '49.2917',
    ),
    24 => 
    array (
      'id' => '7808',
      'name' => 'Tirana International Airport',
      'label' => 'Tirana International Airport',
      'html' => 'Tirana International Airport',
      'lat' => '41.4150929722',
      'lng' => '19.7233001667',
    ),
    25 => 
    array (
      'id' => '20881',
      'name' => 'Tiranë Heliport',
      'label' => 'Tiranë Heliport',
      'html' => 'Tiranë Heliport',
      'lat' => 41.315865416667,
      'lng' => 19.888245972222,
    ),
  ),
  'html' => '<div><b>Search Results for terms \'Iran\'</b>  </div><a class="map-link"  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleMapsSearch(\'name\');">4 results of Names with "Iran"</a><div id="map-results-name" class="map-results-nubbin" style="display:none;"><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'1403\')">Amborovy Airport (Philibert Ts<span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span>ana Airport)</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'6160\')">Generalissimo Francisco De M<span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span>da Airbase</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'7808\')">T<span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span>a International Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'20881\')">T<span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span>ë Heliport</a></div><a class="map-link" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleMapsSearch(\'city\');">4 results of Cities with "Iran"</a><div id="map-results-city" class="map-results-nubbin" style="display:none;"><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5218\')">Abadan, <span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Abadan Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5330\')">Lar, <span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Lar Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'7808\')">T<span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span>a : Tirana International Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'20881\')">T<span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span>a : Tiranë Heliport</a></div><a class="map-link" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleMapsSearch(\'country\');">15 results of Countries with "Iran"</a><div id="map-results-country" class="map-results-nubbin" style="display:none;"><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5218\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Abadan Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5225\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Ahvaz Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5242\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Ardabil Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5243\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Asalouyeh Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5251\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Bandar Abbas International Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5259\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Birjand Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5278\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Dezful Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5306\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Jiroft Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5326\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Konarak Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5330\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Lar Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5331\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Lavan Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5359\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Parsabad-Moghan Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5361\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Persian Gulf Airport (Khalije Fars Airport)</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5393\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Shahid Sadooghi Airport</a><a class="map-sub-links" href="javascript:mapClickHandler(\'5411\')"><span Style="color:red; Font-weight:bold;">Iran</span> : Tabriz International Airport</a></div>',
)
```

And here's what happens when I try to encode it in JSON using Zends_JSON class...

```
{"map":[{"id":"1403","name":"Amborovy Airport (Philibert Tsiranana Airport)","label":"Amborovy Airport (Philibert Tsiranana Airport)","html":"Amborovy Airport (Philibert Tsiranana Airport)","lat":"-0.666944","lng":"46.3517"},{"id":"6160","name":"Generalissimo Francisco de Miranda Airbase","label":"Generalissimo Francisco de Miranda Airbase","html":"Generalissimo Francisco de Miranda Airbase","lat":"0.485","lng":"-66.8436"},{"id":"7808","name":"Tirana International Airport","label":"Tirana International Airport","html":"Tirana International Airport","lat":"41.4150929722","lng":"19.7233001667"},{"id":"20881","name":null,"label":null,"html":null,"lat":41.315865416667,"lng":19.888245972222},{"id":"5218","name":"Abadan Airport","label":"Abadan Airport","html":"Abadan Airport","lat":"0.371111","lng":"48.2283"},{"id":"5330","name":"Lar Airport","label":"Lar Airport","html":"Lar Airport","lat":"0.673056","lng":"54.3814"},{"id":"7808","name":"Tirana International Airport","label":"Tirana International Airport","html":"Tirana International Airport","lat":"41.4150929722","lng":"19.7233001667"},{"id":"20881","name":null,"label":null,"html":null,"lat":41.315865416667,"lng":19.888245972222},{"id":"5218","name":"Abadan Airport","label":"Abadan Airport","html":"Abadan Airport","lat":"0.371111","lng":"48.2283"},{"id":"5225","name":"Ahvaz Airport","label":"Ahvaz Airport","html":"Ahvaz Airport","lat":"0.337431","lng":"48.762"},{"id":"5242","name":"Ardabil Airport","label":"Ardabil Airport","html":"Ardabil Airport","lat":"0.325556","lng":"48.4242"},{"id":"5243","name":"Asalouyeh Airport","label":"Asalouyeh Airport","html":"Asalouyeh Airport","lat":"0.481389","lng":"52.6153"},{"id":"5251","name":"Bandar Abbas International Airport","label":"Bandar Abbas International Airport","html":"Bandar Abbas International Airport","lat":"0.218056","lng":"56.3778"},{"id":"5259","name":"Birjand Airport","label":"Birjand Airport","html":"Birjand Airport","lat":"0.898056","lng":"59.2661"},{"id":"5278","name":"Dezful Airport","label":"Dezful Airport","html":"Dezful Airport","lat":"0.434444","lng":"48.3976"},{"id":"5306","name":"Jiroft Airport","label":"Jiroft Airport","html":"Jiroft Airport","lat":"0.726944","lng":"57.6703"},{"id":"5326","name":"Konarak Airport","label":"Konarak Airport","html":"Konarak Airport","lat":"0.443333","lng":"60.3819"},{"id":"5330","name":"Lar Airport","label":"Lar Airport","html":"Lar Airport","lat":"0.673056","lng":"54.3814"},{"id":"5331","name":"Lavan Airport","label":"Lavan Airport","html":"Lavan Airport","lat":"0.810278","lng":"53.3561"},{"id":"5359","name":"Parsabad-Moghan Airport","label":"Parsabad-Moghan Airport","html":"Parsabad-Moghan Airport","lat":"0.603606","lng":"47.8815"},{"id":"5361","name":"Persian Gulf Airport (Khalije Fars Airport)","label":"Persian Gulf Airport (Khalije Fars Airport)","html":"Persian Gulf Airport (Khalije Fars Airport)","lat":"0.379444","lng":"52.7375"},{"id":"5393","name":"Shahid Sadooghi Airport","label":"Shahid Sadooghi Airport","html":"Shahid Sadooghi Airport","lat":"0.905","lng":"54.2764"},{"id":"5411","name":"Tabriz International Airport","label":"Tabriz International Airport","html":"Tabriz International Airport","lat":"0.133889","lng":"46.235"},{"id":"1416","name":"Arrachart Airport","label":"Arrachart Airport","html":"Arrachart Airport","lat":"-0.349167","lng":"49.2917"},{"id":"7808","name":"Tirana International Airport","label":"Tirana International Airport","html":"Tirana International Airport","lat":"41.4150929722","lng":"19.7233001667"},{"id":"20881","name":null,"label":null,"html":null,"lat":41.315865416667,"lng":19.888245972222}],"html":null}
```

Notice at the end - the humongous clunk of HTML - GONE replaced by a null.... whats happening here :(

---

EDIT

After some investigation I found this error in my error logs:

```
PHP Warning:  json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in C:\wamp\www\fltdata\library\Zend\Json.php
```

I think it might have something to do with the problem I'm facing? How do I fix this?

---

EDIT

My version of Php is 5.2.9-2 - I doubt this is due to the issue which was in versions earlier than 5.2.7... help here guys please!!!

---

EDIT

Running the object through json_encode() returns the same result and I get the same error:

```
PHP Warning:  json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in...
```

I'm stumped here :(

---

SOLUTION

WOO HOOO!!!! I figured it out: I just run the html string variable through a utf8_encode function and then run the JSON encode function on it:

$result['html'] =  utf8_encode($result['html']);

And it works - Thanks everybody for all the help guys - I feel heavily confined by not being able to vote more than once for each of the posts here - you've all been a fanstastic help :D Thanks again!!!

Comment: I had the same problem with PHP's json_encode() some time ago. There where some serious bugs with UTF-8 in this function in older PHP versions (< 5.2.7). What PHP version are you using?

Comment: Note to add: It seems like the php-error you have indicates this exact problem.

Comment: Oh dear - is there some other way around this :(

Comment: I just noticed :-S my version of Php is 5.2.9-2 - isn't that good enough?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You fix this by updating your PHP version to a version later than version 5.2.7.

There was a [serious UTF-8 bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43941) in PHP's [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) function before that version. See the [changelog](http://php.net/changelog) for more details.

---

Since you note that you are using PHP version 5.2.9.2 your version should be good :) Have you tried routing the specific contents of the html through PHP's json_encode() manually?

Or maybe through [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/utf8_encode) or [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/utf8_decode)?

Comment: I'd go with Huppie on this one.

Comment: I just noticed :-S my version of Php is 5.2.9-2 - isn't that good enough?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that manually - what do I need to code I'm just calling a simple:

Zend_Json::encode($obj)

Answer (score 2):

I see only one possible area where NULL may be returned from Encoder.php.  I'd begin debugging by doing some var_dumps inside this function in **Zend/Json/Encoder.php**

```
protected function _encodeDatum(&$value)
{
    $result = 'null';

    if (is_int($value) || is_float($value)) {
        $result = (string) $value;
        $result = str_replace(",", ".", $result);
    } elseif (is_string($value)) {
        $result = $this->_encodeString($value);
    } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
        $result = $value ? 'true' : 'false';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I'm not quite sure why you're HTML string would not be recognized as such, but I might try typecasting it prior to encoding.

```
array('html' => (string) $yourHtmlStr);
```

Comment: Typecasting isn't working at all :( I'm trying to add some var_dumps in the function you mentioned... gimme a while

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if you use `substr()` or use `$somestring[0]` on a utf-8 string which has multibyte letters. Use `mb_` prefixed functions to edit this sort of data, then you will not have problem with `json_encode()`