# Zend::encode + blob

Tags: php, zend-framework, json

Basically, I have a row that contains a blob.

```
$query = "SELECT * from blah"; 
$objects = $db->fetchAll($query);
$output =  Zend_Json::encode($objects);
```

Output has no blob content in it, they are all empty.

My question is - can `Zend_Json` encode handle this or the native `json_encode`?  Or do I have to write a special function to deal with this case?

Whoops i think i can answer my own question at least partially - see here - [Zend_JSON:Encode messing up - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741894/zend-jsonencode-messing-up-why)

Using utf8_encode to parse the binary fixes this issue.

This is an easy solution, but is it the best one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops i think i can answer my own question at least partially - see here - [Zend_JSON:Encode messing up - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741894/zend-jsonencode-messing-up-why)

Using utf8_encode to parse the binary fixes this issue.

This is an easy solution, but is it the best one ?